# Change timezone of given register in MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

we store dates in Europe/Madrid time in our MySQL table as a datetime, in PHP we call them $h

$h is in this format 2017-03-03 17:30:00

I would like to know if there is a simple way to convert this time ($h) to another time zone

something like

```
$h1=changetimezone ($h, 'Europe/Madrid', 'Europe/Dublin')
```

where h1 is h-1hour

resulting for this example 2017-03-03 16:30:00

Thanks

Edit

I tried

```
$h1 = new DateTime($h, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
$h1->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Dublin'));
```

But further down I have

```
$f=strftime('%e/%m/%y %H:%M', strtotime($h1));
```

And i get

```
 strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Edit 2:

Original $h vardump:

```
string(19) "2017-03-03 17:30:00"
```

But it is stored as datetime in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your edit. Try this first

```
$h1 = new DateTime($h, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
$h1->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Dublin'));

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($h1);
```

As you can see this is a DateTime object which cannot be converted directly with `strtotime` since this function waits for a string. Try:

```
$h1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And this is a string.

Second edit to your answer:

```
<?php

$h1 = new DateTime("2017-03-03 17:30:00", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($h1);

$h1->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Dublin'));

var_dump($h1);

var_dump($h1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$f=strftime('%e/%m/%y %H:%M', strtotime($h1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

var_dump($f);
```

Result for me [picture](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1488542268.png)

Comment: That is what i was trying but doesnt work. I edited my question

Comment: Edited my answer. Look for the `Answer to your edit. Try this first` part

Comment: Thanks for your help. Result for 1st: object(DateTime)#1 (0) {} Result for second same:  strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: What is `$h` in your case  ? can you var_dump it and paste the result here ?

Comment: Done. Added vardump of $h

Comment: added some extra code to the end of my answer after `Second edit to your answ:` section. try it

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks a million. Sorry my reputation is too low for my vote to appear

Comment: It is fine :) But I think you can still accept my answer as correct answer. Happy I was able to help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime date_timezone_set ( DateTime $object , DateTimeZone $timezone )`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED thanks to Thank you [Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689724/zolt%C3%A1n-j%C3%A9re), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42576997/3564000) . In summary:

```
$h1 = new DateTime($h, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid')); 
$h1->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($btz)); //$btz is users time zone 'Europe/Dublin'
$f=strftime('%e/%m/%y %H:%M', strtotime($h1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```